# Search Results link to Individual Pages PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite, search

I am making two sites at the moment and have come up to a halt.

Basically I perform a search on the site, it returns all the results, but say I want to click one of the results, and it takes me to a web page of that result, so if I clicked RESULT NUMBER 2001 the URL would end up being something like :

www.mysite.com/?2001

or some variant, whatever it is in PHP.

Thanks in advance; will accept answers in morning!

Comment: You should probably take a look at [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Comment: What's your problem, building the URL, parsing the URL, something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then I believe you would be able to build urls as such...

```
www.mysite.com/?url=2001
```

not...

```
www.mysite.com/?2001
```

With that put aside you would be able to access that number (2001) in your code by using...

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
```

And with that you could easily redirect the user to that page (or whatever page 2001 is) by doing...

```
if($url == 2001)
{
   header("location:http://new-website.com/");
}
```

Hopefully that is what your looking for, next time be more specific on your questions. ;)

Comment: You can in fact use `mysite.com/?2001` by checking `if (isset($_GET["2001"]))`. If you know what other GET variables you're going to have, then you can strip them out, then assume the remaining variable(s) are useful.

Comment: Yes that is what I mean, so for example I have a database of cars, which can be added to constantly.

A user searches through the cars, and chooses one, the only way for it to be unique will be through its id which lets say is 2001, how would I take the user to a page which displays that car, would I have a precreated page which is empty, and when using get will use that ID to generate everything within?

So it will be 

wwwmysite.com/premadeCars?car=2001  

? 

Thanks again!